# How to check if an element has a jQuery UI widget initialized (slider, datepicker, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

The slider widget has a destroy method, but obviously it can only be called if the slider has been initialized into a specific element. I am trying to find a way to detect if the element has been initialized with the slider widget, if so then use the destroy method.

Something like this:

```
if($('#myElm').slider() != NULL){
    $('#myElm').slider('destroy');
}

$('#myElm').slider({
   //new parameters
});
```

I thought of creating a flag variable to detect if it has been initialized for the first time or not, but I am sure there must a more elegant way of checking the status of the element's jquery widgets.

This applies to any other UI Widget like calendar:
https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy

```
if($('#myElm').datepicker() != NULL){
   $('#myElm').datepicker("destroy");
}
```

or tabs (https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-destroy)

```
if($('#myElm').tabs() != NULL){
   $('#myElm').tabs( "destroy" );
}
```

I believe all the Widgets have a destroy method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Twisty Gives very good solutions but I found this to be the most elegant

```
if (typeof $('#myElm').slider() !== "undefined") {
    $('#myElm').slider("destroy");
}
```

And this applies for any other method.

```
if (typeof $('#myElm').datepicker() !== "undefined") {
    $('#myElm').datepicker("destroy");
}

if (typeof $('#myElm').tabs() !== "undefined") {
    $('#myElm').tabs("destroy");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the Instance method:

> **instance()** Returns: Object

> Retrieves the slider's instance object. If the element does not have an associated instance, undefined is returned.

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-instance

```
if($('#myElem').slider("instance") != undefined){
  $('#myElem').slider("destroy");
}
```

Datepicker is the black sheep of the widgets, docs do not show an `instance`, so you could look for the `.data()` or the `widget`.

```
var dtp = $(".selector").data("ui-datepicker");
if(dtp.length){
  $(".selector").datepicker("destroy");
}
```